# How to modify files on Unix to avoid file purging policy?

Tags: bash, command-line, find

We have a policy on our cluster that any files not modified or accessed within 30 days will be deleted. I have a project running and I want to keep all files until I finish it, would it be possible to trick the system by doing something like:

```
find ./ -type f -exec touch {} +
```

I have tried this and it seems that the time-stamp changes, but will that fool the system into thinking that the files have actually been modified?

Comment: If the system looks at the modified date, yes.

Comment: It depends on how the delete script works, but, yes, most such delete scripts (like tmpwatch) use the mtime, so that should be fine. I'd use `find . -print0 | xargs -0 touch` (which would touch the directories as well), but that's just personal preference.

Comment: Did you consider using [git](http://git-scm.com/) for your project (and host a repository elsewhere, e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)...)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It is a computational chemistry project with hundreds of files ranging from 500 Mb to 3 Gb. I don't think github can handle that.

Comment: Strikes me that it would be better (although not necessarily easier) to go and speak with the system administrators - via your supervisor if necessary - and ask them not to remove your files while your project is in progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure this should work.

But you make sure by check with 'stat' command.

```
sh-4.3$ stat test.csv                                                              
File: 'test.csv'                                                                 
Size: 871             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file           
Device: 20fd4bh/2161995d        Inode: 8389896     Links: 1                        
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      cg)   Gid: ( 1000/      cg)           
Access: 2016-01-06 05:29:32.220197637 +0000                                        
Modify: 2016-01-06 05:29:32.220197637 +0000                                        
Change: 2016-01-06 05:29:32.220197637 +0000                                        
Birth: -                                                                          
sh-4.3$
```

Answer (score 3):

If the policy is really “files not modified or accessed within 30 days”, then you can set the files' access times by running `touch -a` instead of plain `touch`. The advantage of doing it that way is that it doesn't disrupt the modification times, so it won't break build scripts and you can keep using the modification time as an indication of how old this version of the file is.

You can see a file's access time with `ls -lu`.

Comment: Just as long as the person writing the human-readable version of the cluster purge policy is familiar enough with boolean logic that he/she didn't write "files not modified or accessed within 30 days" when what was actually implemented was "files either not modified within 30 days or not accessed within 30 days."  ;)